# How to bring up the same php file with different information using term search

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP/HTML, so I don't really know what I'm talking about, but how would I use PHP to make it so instead of having to make a new html file, for example, I have a navigation bar with the letters A-Z. When you click one of the letters, instead of it bringing you to say W.html, it instead just finds the information that would be on W, and directs it into say the div on index.html?
Is that possible? Or something similar to that?

Comment: this is basically asking what is PHP. you should go to http://php.net and start from there.

Comment: See this http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally were I doing as you suggest, a navigation bar that brings dynamic content into the current document, I would rely on Javascript (specifically JQuery) to accomplish my goal.

This way you can either go back to your server and ask your PHP/DB stack for the appropriate content or you can just expose a hidden element () that already contains the data.

Here is a link to get you started:
http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this with on-page anchors. Your navigation menu would look like this:

```
<a href="index.html#A">A</a>
<a href="index.html#B">B</a>
<a href="index.html#C">C</a>
<a href="index.html#D">D</a>
<a href="index.html#E">E</a>
```

etc.

Then, in your `index.html` you need to create the appropriate named anchors:

```
<a name="A">A Section</a>
<a name="B">B Section</a>
<a name="C">C Section</a>
<a name="D">D Section</a>
<a name="E">E Section</a>
```